# OSGi just won't launch upon Domino server startup, out of ideas

Tags: eclipse, osgi, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

In trying to load the latest Extension Library, (9.0.1.v00_11_20141217-1000)
using the UpdateSite.nsf on a Windows server, OSGi just doesn't want to come up after issuing:

```
tell http quit 
load http
```

Even after restarting the server with the OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES set to my servers' updatesite.nsf and after importing the site.xml for the Extension Library from OpenNTF.   I 've signed the contents, signed the database, checked the Security in the Server Doc.

Here's what gets loaded, dated 2014-08-01:

> **tell http osgi ss com.ibm.xsp.extlib**
>
> `> [1084:0002-06D0] 01/27/2015 10:19:04 AM  Framework is launched.`
>   `> [1084:0002-06D0] 01/27/2015 10:19:04 AM  id State       Bundle`
>   `> [1084:0002-06D0] 01/27/2015 10:19:04 AM  90 <<LAZY>>`
>   `> com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000`
>   `> [1084:0002-06D0] 01/27/2015 10:19:04 AM  91 <<LAZY>>`
>   `> com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000 [1084:0002-06D0]`
>   `> 01/27/2015 10:19:04 AM  92 <<LAZY>>`
>   `> com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000 [1084:0002-06D0]`
>   `> 01/27/2015 10:19:04 AM  93 <<LAZY>>`
>   `> com.ibm.xsp.extlib.mobile_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000 [1084:0002-06D0]`
>   `> 01/27/2015 10:19:04 AM  94 <<LAZY>>`
>   `> com.ibm.xsp.extlib.oneui_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000 [1084:0002-06D0]`
>   `> 01/27/2015 10:19:04 AM  95 <<LAZY>>`
>   `> com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20140801-1000`

My **Startup** inside C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Domino\data\domino\workspace\logs 
reveals this:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows Server 2008 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr16-20140416_196573 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20140416_196573
JIT  - r9_20130920_46510ifx5
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR16_20140416_1614_B196573
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -noSplash true true true
Command-line arguments:  -console -data C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/Domino/data/domino/workspace -noSplash true -clean true -noExit true

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-01-26 17:44:59.307
**!MESSAGE Bundle com.ibm.domino.osgi.core@15 not found.**

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2015-01-26 17:44:59.619
```

**    !MESSAGE C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Domino\data\domino\workspace.config\domino\eclipse\plugins\plugins is not a valid plugins directory. **

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 4 0 2015-01-26 17:44:59.822
!MESSAGE Could not install bundle ../../shared/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.domino.http.ssl_9.0.1.20140801-1000.jar   Bundle "com.ibm.domino.http.ssl" version "9.0.1.20140801-1000" has already been installed from: initial@reference:file:../../shared/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.domino.http.ssl_9.0.1.20140801-1000.jar/
```

Does anyone have a suggestion what to do about this?

Comment: make sure extlib is not copied to filesystem

Comment: This just crossed my mind: is the file name of the update site database exactly the same as the notes.ini variable? Once ran into this issue when having an UpdateSite.nsf. I now always stick to lowercase.

Comment: @Mark .. Thanks for that idea; I revised the notes.ini parameter to look for the file in lowercase.  It didn't make any difference.   I'll be in touch soon.

Answer (score 1):

If your server's version matches with the used Extlib version (9.0.1) then please check if you have other plugins installed via the file system (as Frantisek mentioned). Check the folder `<YourDominoBinary>\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins`
for JAR files that contain "extlib" and "8.5.3". This might occur if you upgraded from 8.5.3 to 9.0.x so the files were not removed. Normally you wouldn't run into trouble but I had that scenario, too, and all I had to do was to delete them / move them elsewhere. After that the plugin files from your updatesite should load.

Another idea: the Extlib package contains 2 versions: one for DDE, one for the server. Please check that you put the right one into your updatesite.

Always remember to restart the server completely (after modifying notes.ini) or to restart the HTTP task completely via "restart task http" after modifying your updatesite content.

Comment: @Frantisek & @Oliver :  Thanks for the helping hand! 

This is a fresh new Domino server and installation, so there are no hang-over files from previous versions.

There are tons of JAR files and related sub-folders full of stuff in the ..\Shared\Plugins\ folder..  Is it really a `guessing game` which files I'm to know which files and folders to remove (to a safekeeping folder)?   

I tried removing just the JAR files from the plugins folder and restarted Domino only to see it not report the OSGi preference and also to see the same old 2014-08 files in console having a `<<Lazy>>` status.